# How do you stop a webpage from loading in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, browser

There's a stop button in Internet Explorer and Firefox, but there isn't one in Google Chrome.  Some pages takes too long to load and I would like the browser to stop trying to load it.

**How do you stop a webpage from loading in Google Chrome?**

Is there a shortcut key at all?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The "go" button (a triangle) on the right side of the address bar becomes the **stop button (a cross)** while the page is loading.

Answer (score 55):

Press <kbd>Escape</kbd>. Alternatively the refresh button *should* be changed to a stop button.

Comment: also a correct answer.

Comment: I now noticed Chromium does not have a Go/Stop button (see Shaji's answer), whereas Google Chrome does.

Comment: Chrome v29 doesnt have Esc to stop 'feature', at least in mac.

Comment: In Windows, I've found that in some situations it works, but in others it doesn't. I think it's related to the web page intercepting the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key for another purpose. For example, the Google home page seems to use the key to move text input focus back to the search box.

Comment: Useless with anything that runs on new threads like popups/timers etc. as they are created at initialisation.

Comment: If the escape key isn't working try hitting the X button super quickly otherwise it can hang on page load and escape won't work.

Comment: The best answer